# Excel macro changed ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues but the text remained unchanged

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VB or VBA, but recent work with Excel requires a huge number of repetitions. That's why I am now considering the VBA macro approach to simplify the process.

The work is simple - to generate charts with given data. But there are hundreds of charts to create, so I used copy and paste to keep the style consistency, and changed the values within afterwards.

Everything worked out pretty well with the data, but not so smooth with the axis label. I was tring to use `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=<sheet_name>!$<row_num>$<col_num>"` to modify the value to some existing text in the respective cells, but it didn't work out on the chart, i.e., if the label was "total", as is in the A6 cell, in the original chart that I copied from, after selecting the pasted chart and executing the command above, the label in the new chart still says "total" instead of what's in the, say, B6 cell, which for example is "China". But when I right clicked the chart and went into "select data", the "Horizontal (Catagory) Axis Label" is indeed changed into "=sheet1!$B$6", which made me very confused.

Anyone knows how this happened and how to fix this? Is there an "update" method to the chart object or anything that I've been missing?

I am currently using Excel 2010.

Comment: After automating an Excel object to change the data, you need to call the (Excel) application's Update method before quitting. I'm not sure if it does other things under the hood, but it updates the metafile representation of the underlying data.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the strange world of Excel VBA.

`SeriesCollection().XValues` requires either a `Range` object or an array of points, so you must transform your string into a range:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(<sheet_name>).Range("$<row_num>$<col_num>")
```

Comment: That seems to make sense. :) (I didn't try it out though. The workload was so heavy that I had to keep on doing other part of the job, and after that I totally forgot to come back and check. Sorry about that >_<)

Comment: +1 Do you know why the version with string worked on the computer on which the macro was generated? I just tried C&P and had the same problem until I saw your answer.